# VSTS hosted builds/Docker: "The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version."

Tags: docker, dockerfile, azure-pipelines, docker-machine

On a hosted VSTS windows build, I execute ea batch file executing some Docker related operations. One command is:

> docker-compose build

The build runs perfectly until this DockerFile command:

> RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y install cron -qq --force-yes && apt-get -y install nginx -qq --force-yes

I get this error:

[image]

This error is not seen when building on my developer box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48880165/600559). The Windows agent is configured to use Windows containers - not Linux containers.